# Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

1. I am using mono(4.0.4) to build and run .NET applications on ubuntu 14.04
2. installed and configured libuv(1.4.2)
3. installed dnvm(1.0.0-rc2-15539) and latest dnx (1.0.0-beta8)
4. when i try to run with **dnx . kestrel** i get "Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web, kestrel."

Answer (score 1):

As of beta-7 `.` has [been removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/52). So, you should run your app with `dnx kestrel` and not `dnx . kestrel`.